# C read value from config file

Tags: c, parsing, config

> I need help with reading a port from a config file. The line looks like:
>   PORT=8888

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int ac, char **av)
{

        char buf[256];
        FILE *file = NULL;
        char hostlist[256] = "";
        int port = 8080; /* default not from config */
        int i = 0;
```

> ```
>   // open file
>   // some feof code
> ```
>
> [..]

```
        strcpy(hostlist,buf);
        if (strstr(buf,"PORT")) {      /* buf[0-3] = */
                printf("%c\n",buf[5]); /* PORT=8888 */
                printf("%c\n",buf[6]);
                printf("%c\n",buf[7]);
                printf("%c\n",buf[8]);
```

> This works as expected ^^
>      But, when trying to copy into a buffer I get nothing for
>      port or I get the default port.

```
                for(i=4;i<9;i++) {
                while (buf[i] != '\n') {
                port += buf[i++];
                printf("buf:%c\n",buf[i]);
                }
                }
                printf("port=%d\n",port);
        }
        fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: now, that's a lot of bugs in such a tiny code... `i=4`? `port +=`? interesting decimal system. also.. adding character to an integer? and that double loop is just plain ugly.

Comment: `port += buf[i++];` is most likely a bug as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question, but I assume you intend to do something like this:

```
char* ptr_port = strstr(buf,"PORT=");
if(ptr_port != NULL)
{
  int port = get_port(ptr_port);

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", ptr_port[i]);
  }       
  printf("\n");
  printf("port=%d\n", port);
}


#include <ctype.h>
int get_port (const char* str)
{
  int port = 0;

  for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    if(isdigit(str[i]))
    {
      port = port*10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
  }

  return port;
}
```

Comment: Please check the code, you are just summing the digits & returning the sum ^^... You need something like multiplication of `port` by 10 in each iteration & return with correction.  Nit pick: `strstr(buf,"PORT");` should be `strstr(buf,"PORT=");` as per OP for correct printing

Answer (score 8):

You should probably just use `fscanf()`:

```
if(fscanf(file, "PORT=%d", &port) == 1)
{
  print("Found port number in config, it's %d\n", port);
}
```

Comment: `if(fscanf(file, "PORT=%d", &port) == 1)
        {
         if ((port +0)<0 || port > 65536|| port == 0 )  {
                 printf("port out of range\n");
                exit(1); } else
                printf("port=%d, default=%d\n", port, save);
                }
        return(0);}`